# Smooth curve confusion

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, curves, smooth-functions

I am reading a book that somehow gives two different definitions for a smooth curve, so I wonder which one is more precise.

Suppose we're given the curve $L$ defined by the parametric equation
$$(x,y)=(f(t),g(t)),\quad t\in[a,b].$$

The first definition I encountered is that this curve is said to be smooth if $f'$ and $g'$ exist in the interval $[a,b]$ and also they are not simultaneously zero at any point $\theta \in [a, b]$.

The second definition I encountered is that this curve is said to be smooth if $f'$ and $g'$ exist in the interval $[a,b]$ and they are also continuous in $[a,b]$. I think the definition given here also matches my second definition.

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmoothCurve.html

But to me the first definition makes more sense because smooth somehow seems to be mean that the curve has a tangent line at any point. Isn't that what smooth is?

So I am very confused here.

1. Do we need to require $f'$ and $g'$ to be continuous?
2. Do we need to require that $f'$, $g'$ are both simultaneously zero at any point $\theta \in [a,b]$?
3. Also, what happens really if $f'$ and $g'$ are simultaneously zero at some point? I mean, the book says that then the curve has no tangent at that point. OK, but how does it look like at that point? Does it have more than one tangent there, or no tangent at all? Any examples?

I also constructed two examples myself. Here they are.

4. Is this curve smooth? Why?
   $$(x,y) = (t^5 \cos(t), t^2),\quad t \in [-\pi, \pi]$$
5. What about this one? Why?
   $$(x,y) = t^2 \cos(t), t^5),\quad t \in [-\pi, \pi]$$

For $t=0$ both $f'$ and $g'$ are equal to zeros (for both curves).

Please someone more knowledgeable clear these confusions.

Note that I am asking just in a normal calculus (real analysis) context. I mean, I don't need complicated generalizations, just an explanation in this particular context.

Comment: This is weird, certainly $f’$ and $g’$ need be continuous, but the condition that they’re non zero feels superfluous, as that’s the definition of a curve immersed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which presupposes that the curve is smooth.

Comment: If $f’=g’=0$ at some point inside the interval, then the curve may have a cusp or corner there.  For instance, start at $(1,0)$, travel to the origin with constant linear deceleration such that your speed is zero when you reach it, and then move to $(0,1)$ with constant linear acceleration.

Comment: @Chris So basically you're saying the 2nd definition is the correct one?

Comment: @peter.petrov I know you told us not talk about more advanced mathematics, but that's definition I'd used in differential topology

Comment: There are several different definitions in the literature for "smooth function", two of which are much more commonly used than anything else -- functions with continuous first derivatives and functions that are infinitely differentiable (the latter equivalent to every finite order derivative exists and is continuous). Regarding nonzero derivatives, this is usually what a ["regular curve" (or "regular smooth curve") means](https://www.google.com/search?q=differential+geometry+%22regular+curve%22).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Ah, I think I see. So the two examples I gave... these are smooth curves (in the 1st sense of your two), but not regular smooth curves. Correct?

Comment: *Correct?* -- That's what I recall from a couple of (beginning; no manifolds stuff) differential geometry classes I was in during the late 1970s (one of which I only audited), and googling seems to confirm this. Of course, with math terms (and notation), it's always best to be aware that conventions can vary, so it's important to not think what you read in one place will apply at another place -- you need to double check that what you read in one place actually applies (or at least appears to apply) at the other place. And be aware of the fact that typos and inadvertent omissions can occur!